# finding the unique number of text values with criteria

Tags: excel, unique

I have a dataset as in the fig.
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBoU.jpg)

Now, I need to find the unique number of people working for each project. I have used this formula
{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(criteria,MATCH(values,values,0)),ROW(values)-ROW(values.firstcell)+1)>0))}

But as the number of data entries increases, this formula is not displaying the correct result. My doubt is that in the formula, "ROW(values.firstcell)" is being changed for each project. Am I getting an error because of this or should I be using any other formula. Plz suggest.
Thank you

Comment: I dont want a pivot table as there are more conditions that need to be added.

Comment: What is the exact formula you are using in G4?  Please put that in the original post and not pseudo code.  The formula will work so it must be how you are using it.

Comment: One more thing you are probably not aware of.  When given an answer to your question one should mark it as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.  I went through your history and you have gotten answers to your questions but not marked any as correct. Only the one posing the question can choose which answer is correct.

Comment: ROW(values.firstcell) should be absolute reference. prefix both column and row with $

Answer (score 0):

Enter the below formula in the cell G4 as control array and copy the same to below columns.

```
{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B:B=F4,MATCH(A:A,A:A,0)),ROW(A:A)-ROW($A$1)+1)>0))}
```